# Can a website infect a computer without the user's assistance?

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you get virus just by visiting a website in chrome](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/can-you-get-virus-just-by-visiting-a-website-in-chrome)

I have a hard time believing that [drive-by downloads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download) can actually happen without a user's assistance (e.g. without the user clicking a popup and downloading a program).

To test this, I've set up a virtual machine with IE 6 on it (no updates!), but then I got stuck -- when I looked at [Norton's Top 100 Dirtiest websites](http://safeweb.norton.com/dirtysites), all of them seemed clean (clicking on their report says they're not infected). Subsequently browsing a couple confirmed this point.

Is a drive-by download even possible? Any simple proof/examples of sites that do this?

Comment: @RoryAlsop: I was looking for some sort of example, not a mere assertion that it's true. Obviously the latter was already in the Wikipedia article...

Comment: I wanted to answer to you here to this interesting question but I can since it is marked duplicate. You can find 3 examples of what you asked here via an answer to the question supposed to be the duplicate of yours.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. The problem is that as soon as a known security breach exists, the company which wrote the browser books it to patch the hole, so it is hard to find a concrete example.

One classic example of "drive-by download" is being able to write to disk without the user's consent. [One such exploit](http://www.loopinsight.com/2011/03/09/safari-hacked-in-five-seconds-at-pwn2own/) was shown in Safari last year. What's worse, is that that specific security breach also allowed malicious agents to activate an app on the Mac, kinda scary.

Comment: Right, that's why I have an old version of IE 6 handy for testing this. So it should work on that, shouldn't it?

Comment: You might be able to find something, but I can't really give you a demonstration, only a listing which says that it *has* happened.

Comment: "Books it?" That is a new expression to me. What does it mean?

Comment: @MetaEd It means that they rush as fast as possible.