# I got IP logged, now what?

Tags: ip

Long story short, I clicked a link on my phone that someone sent me. It contained an IP-logger. What information did they get from it? I'm scared because they have my IP, and god knows what other info. How bad is this and what should I do? What can they do with it?

Comment: Not too much if ip is the only thing you gave to them

Comment: Any website you visit without going through a vpn/proxy/anonymiser/etc... will know your IP address and will most likely store it in its logs somewhere.  I'm not sure what makes your case more dangerous than regular browsing.

Comment: The most they could possibly have from you clicking the link is your browser user agent (which just says things like the browser version you use), and your IP itself. The worst they could do is try to knock you offline by spamming your IP with garbage information or figure out your rough geographic location, but even that is unlikely. Most likely whoever did that to you is some script kiddie trying to scare you or an angry video game rival who's salty about losing and wants to disconnect you from the game.

Answer (score 3):

Having your IP logged is not a big deal. Every single site you visit (and every single subresource they load, like ads) gets your IP. All your IP says is what ISP you use, and what general part of the world you are probably located in. Especially if you are using a phone your IP changes often (e.g. as soon as you switch to a new cell tower) and you probably already have a new one.

So don't worry to much about someone knowing your IP. But still, visiting shady websites [isn't without risk](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/can-you-get-virus-just-by-visiting-a-website-in-chrome), it's just not directly related to IP logging.

Answer (score 1):

If they only have your IP address, that is not a very big deal, obviously this depends on the capabilities of that "IP-logger", if the IP-logger that you mentioned is an App that you installed, then there is a possibility that the owners can get more info about you. Otherwise, you should know that every website that you visit is logging your IP address and more information, you can search for an Apache access log if you want more details of what information a web server can save when you make a request to it. Also it is important to mention that nowadays IP addresses are dynamic, the IP address that you have this moment could change in some hours or just the next time that you turn off/turn on your router.